# How to succesfully implement a cashier prompt in a while loop?

Tags: java

According to an excercise: 
"A pet shop wants to give a discount to its
clients if they buy one or more pets and
at least five other items. The discount is
equal to 20 percent of the cost of the other
items, but not the pets.

Implement a method
public static void discount(double[] prices, boolean[] isPet, int nItems)
The method receives information about a particular sale. For the ith item, prices[i] is
the price before any discount, and isPet[i] is true if the item is a pet.

Write a program that prompts a cashier to enter each price and then a Y for a pet or N
for another item. Use a price of –1 as a sentinel. Save the inputs in an array. Call the
method that you implemented, and display the discount."

I have made the discount() method but I fail to create a cashier prompt through a while loop. The excercise's book gives me these 
[Tips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0DUN.png)
.This is what I have tried:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


    public class Pet {


        public static void main(String[] args) {



            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            double[] prices = new double[10];
            boolean[] isPet = new boolean[5];
            int items = 0;
            int count = 0;
            System.out.println("Hello. Please enter all prices, pets and items.");

            String input = in.nextLine(); 

            while(!input.equals("-1")){
               count++; 
               if(input.equals("Y")){
                   items++;
                   isPet[items] = true;
               }
               if(input.equals("N")){
                   items++;
               }
               if(!input.equals("Y") && !input.equals("N")){
                   double price = Double.parseDouble(input);
                   prices[count] = price;
               }
            }

        }

         public void discount(double[] prices, boolean[] isPet, int nItems){
             double total = 0;   
             double petTotal = 0;
             double realTotal = 0;
             int rItems = nItems;
             for(int i = 0; i < prices.length; i++){
                    total = total + prices[i];
                    if(isPet[i]){
                        rItems = rItems - 1;
                        petTotal = petTotal + prices[i];
                    }
             }
             for(int i = 0; i < isPet.length; i++){
                 int count = 0;
                 if(isPet[i] && rItems >= 5 && count < 2){
                  count++;
                  total = total - petTotal;   
                  realTotal = total * 0.80;
                  realTotal = realTotal + petTotal;
                  System.out.println(realTotal);
             }
                if(rItems < 5){
                    System.out.println(total);
                }         
             }
         }
    }
```

And it's obviously wrong and I don't know how to interpret the excercise and the tips! I'm totally confused could someone help me in finding way on "How to implement a cashier prompt through while loops" succesfully according to this excercise. Or perhaps give me a pseudo code/logic for this excercise? I thank you for your time.

Comment: So you mean to say that you are unable to read the user input multiple times ?

Comment: Stackoverflow was not invented for doing your homework.

Comment: I'm unable to understand the excercise, understand what kind of loops I need to make, and understand how I should make those loops add to the boolean[] isPet, the double[] prices, and increment the item variable.

Comment: If you don't understand the exercise, ask your teacher about it. If you have a specific programming problem, ask a specific question about it and provide [mcve] rather than dumping entire homework at us. Familiarizing yourself with this page will help you as well: [ask]

Comment: The only thing I will tell you. You will encounter a Banana problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is apparent that there are a lot of issues with your code, but you are on the right lines so don't give up. I will give you a few pointers in terms of possible directions to take to fulfilling the task requirements.

I propose your initial focus should be on your while loop for gathering the data from the user. You are nearly there, `while(!input.equals("-1"))` does indeed seem like the correct approach. **But** you are only getting the user to input data **once**, which is above the loop with `String input = in.nextLine();`.
What you want is to update the `input` variable in the loop with the user's next purchase, so `input = in.nextLine();` would suffice (maybe consider using ints).

Then once you've got this functioning correctly then focus on the discount method.

Here's a quick example of a functioning while loop which will gather the data you need, play around with it and try to understand it.

```
    System.out.println("Please enter all prices, pets and items.");
    String input = in.nextLine();

    while (!"-1".equals(input)) {
        System.out.println("Please enter all prices, pets and items.");
        input = in.nextLine();
    }
```